# Como puedo saber si un servidor permite JSONP o CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp

Quiero utilizar una API de una pagina de Wallpapers pero me tope con la restriccion de dominios crusados de ajax. Investigue acerca del error y se puede solucionar al utilizar JSONP de JQuery para tomar la información que retorna la API. Esta es mi solicitud.

```
$.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: { 'auth': apikey ,
                'method':'search',
                'term': keyword},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

También probé de esta manera

```
$.getJSON(urlsearch+"?callback=?",function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
```

No funciona de ninguna de las dos formas. Ya revisé que la API funcione correctamente, Este es el error que aparece en firebug.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí que talvez el servidor no soporte JSONP ni CORS y que una solución puede ser crear un script en PHP que obtenga la información y la transfiera a javascript. Pero no estoy seguro que sea la mejor forma de hacerlo. ¿Alguien conoce alguna solución?.

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: esa información debe encontrase en la API. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Si la página tiene una API, entonces lo más común es que tenga el `CORS` activado. Sin embargo, el hecho que lo tenga no quiere decir que te puedas conectar si no es pública. En este caso, necesitarías autenticarte (usuario/contraseña, token, llave, etc.)
2. Si desconoces el punto `1`, pues haces una simple petición al servidor para analizar la respuesta. Si no admite `CORS` lo podrás ver en la respuesta.

Según lo que muestra tu código, estás **autenticándote** ante el servidor **con una llave** (`'auth': apikey`). Y esto se refleja en la consola, ya que **sí estás obteniendo respuesta** (se puede ver que llega un array de objetos con datos como ancho y alto).

---

El mensaje que obtienes:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Es probable porque:

> #### JSON != JSONP

`JSON` no es lo mismo que `JSONP`. Una respuesta `JSONP` es básicamente un `script` que contiene **una ejecución de una función** (predeterminada). Un ejemplo de una respuesta `JSONP`:

```
functionPredeterminada({
  wallpaper: 'http://hdwallpapers.in?abc=14578',
  width: 2560,
  height: 1600
})
```

---

#### Conclusión

Lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar `jsonp` por `json` en orden de tener un `JSON` válido.

```
$.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'auth': apikey ,
                'method':'search',
                'term': keyword},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias por responder, ya intente con json normal pero aparece este error y no aparece en encabezado CORS [Imagen](https://k61.kn3.net/3/C/D/6/8/D/C53.png)

Comment: ¿En esa web se requiere que añadas los dominios desde dónde se realizará la petición? Fíjate que la respuesta que devuelve tiene el mime `application/json` mas no `application/javascript` que mayormente tiene una respuesta `JSONP`.

Comment: No, Unicamente la API Key y en los ejemplos de uso que estan hechos con PHP unicamente utilizan la API Key